# How to setup "git cluster"

Tags: git, installation

We are thinking of changing our source version control system from Subversion to Git. We're pushing the limits on our current setup and think we'll be better of working with git.

We've always used a primary server in the office, and a mirror running at our datacenter. The mirror is configured to proxy incoming commits to the primary server. This way the two machines operated as if it was a single repository, enabling us to commit to the office machine when we are in the office or to the datacenter machine when we are somewhere else.

Having two machines is saving us alot of bandwidth and increases speed, which for us is important because we use subversion as our primary deployment tool too.

Recently we acquired a development shop in India and they will be working on the same code. Because of bandwidth limits and latency issues, having a mirror in India would be very convenient too.

As we are switching to Git, we are looking for a similar setup. How can I make multiple git repositories act as one? Ideally I'd like commits to a repository to automatically propagate to the other servers for the same repository.

Comment: If you'd like to use gitolite, its documentation has some guidance about how to set up mirroring: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/mirroring.mkd

Comment: The one thing you can't really do, as it says in that document, is have users push to multiple repositories. That's a recipe for headaches - imagine what would happen if two users pushed at the same time to different repos. Fortunately, the heavier operation is fetching (especially cloning), and mirrors will work just fine for that.

Comment: updated link to gitolite mirroring: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/mirroring.html

Answer (score 1):

Latency won't be an issue for you in general because you'll commit locally.  You may not need to do anything at all.  Pushes and pulls can get slower, though.  If that bothers you, there are lots of things you can do.

We use [github](http://github.com/) as our "authoritative" tree, but we don't push there (our [code review system](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) does) and our builders (and some developers) don't pull from there.

Every push to github fires a [post-receive hook](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) to one or more instances of my [gitmirror](https://github.com/dustin/gitmirror) project which does an immediate mirror fetch.  These mirrors are generally always updated within about a second of github.  If anything happens to the central repo, it's quite possible others won't even notice it.

Comment: I should probably note that I wrote gitmirror initially for use outside of github where I was using a post-commit hook to notify a different server that things were updated and the updates should be replicated.  github isn't an important part here, though the post-receive hook makes things pretty easy.